# Combinations for arranging words in a grid, with up to 3 letters allowed per box

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Edit: I have completely reworded this question to be more math-friendly.

How many ways can a 'word*' be 'divvied*' up into 'boxes*'?

A box is a letter container that may contain up to N letters of a word. The order of the letters in the box matters.

*Divvying of a word* means "to spread out, or disburse, the words' letters between box(es), in such a way that setting non-empty boxes adjacent to one another creates a correct spelling of the original word.

A word is a string of 'X' letters in which the order of the letters matters.

I might have a further question about re-understanding this with "uniqueness" in mind, but I don't actually need to know that right now I do not think.

Example Word - Telecommunication

Divvied Up One Configuration

Tel-eco-mmu-nic-ati-on

One More Configuration

T-el-e-com-u-nic-ati-o-n